# String.Replace not working on long html code. (Mail.Body)

Tags: html, string, text, replace, document-body

So, I just came across a minor problem, given a mail object:

```
Mail = new MailMessage();
```

Generating it's body:

```
Mail.IsBodyHtml = true; 
Mail.Body = GenerateHTMLFoo(); // it's a stringbuilder
```

Now Mail.Body contains a whole HTML document, just showing the first line for example:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">
```

Then I send the mail, and after that I would like to replace something in it's body:

```
Mail.Body.Replace("cid:header", "header.jpg"); // no effect
```

Any ideas? Mail.Body is a string, and the replacing has no effect on it.

Comment: Can you post some example output of stringBuilder function. I dont think anyone can help this, without looking into the actual src string

Comment: Added an example line. It's full of slashes, that might be the problem?

Comment: I could not see any syntax error with your code.

Comment: It's probably the IDE displaying the content of the StringBuilder this way. Still not a reason for replace methods to not work.

Comment: This a helpful title i found hope it helps: [ASP.net c# replace string not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854465/asp-net-c-sharp-replace-string-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with this, but I'm still curious why it didn't worked the "normal" way.

```
            MailBody = new StringBuilder(Mail.Body);
            MailBody.Replace("cid:header", "header.jpg");
            Mail.Body = MailBody.ToString();
```