# C++ String->Replace not working as expected

Tags: .net, string, c++-cli, user-defined-functions, str-replace

I'm trying to create a program that generates mad-lib style stories for planets in a universe simulation game that I own. It's designed so that a user can type in story templates in a .txt file with the variables in the story templates placed inside of percent signs. The program reads the .txt files, pulls the stories, finds the variables, and fills in the variables with the appropriate random information (currently, there are only two variables that I've defined).

The problem that I am having is that it's not replacing the variables in the story, even though all of my attempts to debug it (as you will see in the code/output) shows that the computer generates appropriate text, and recognizes that the variable is there in the text.

The actual line that's the issue is down near the bottom inside the "GetVar()" function definition.

Full Program (minus control initialization to shorten things up):

```
#pragma once
namespace SpaceEngineStoryTeller {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;
/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void) {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1() {
        delete components;
    }
private:
    System::Windows::Forms::TabControl^  tabControl1;
    System::Windows::Forms::TabPage^  tabPage1;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    System::Windows::Forms::TabPage^  tabPage2;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
    System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  TemperatureBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label11;
    System::Windows::Forms::TabPage^  tabPage3;
    System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  ExportBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label10;
    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
    System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  ImportBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label9;
    System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  StoryBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;
    System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  LifeBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label13;
    System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  TypeBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label12;
    System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  AtmosphereBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label15;
    System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  GravityBox;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label14;
    System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label16;
    System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  SubglacialCheck;
    System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  TerrestrialCheck;
    System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  MarineCheck;
    System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  FloatersCheck;
    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox3;
    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox2;
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    int StoriesCtr, SpaceRacesCtr, NonSpaceRacesCtr, varctr, RndHolder, ArrayLength, StoryLength;
    Random ^ Rnd;
    String^ path;
    static array<String^>^ var=gcnew array<String^>(65535);
    static array<String^>^ Stories=gcnew array<String^>(65535);
    static array<String^>^ subStory=gcnew array<String^>(65535);
    static array<String^>^ SpaceRaces=gcnew array<String^>(65535);
    static array<String^>^ NonSpaceRaces=gcnew array<String^>(65535);
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
private:
    void InitializeComponent(void) {
        //Omitted Code
    }
#pragma endregion
private:
    System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        StoriesCtr=0;
        SpaceRacesCtr=0;
        NonSpaceRacesCtr=0;
        varctr=0;
        ArrayLength=0;
        Rnd=gcnew Random;
        path="C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SpaceEngine Story Teller\\Resources\\Stories.txt";
        StreamReader^ StoryReader = gcnew StreamReader(path, true);
        while(StoryReader->EndOfStream==false) {
            Stories[StoriesCtr]=StoryReader->ReadLine();
            StoriesCtr++;
        }
        StoryReader->Close();
        path="C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SpaceEngine Story Teller\\Resources\\SpaceRaces.txt";
        StreamReader^ SpaceRacesReader = gcnew StreamReader(path, true);
        while(SpaceRacesReader->EndOfStream==false) {
            SpaceRaces[SpaceRacesCtr]=SpaceRacesReader->ReadLine();
            SpaceRacesCtr++;
        }
        SpaceRacesReader->Close();
        path="C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SpaceEngine Story Teller\\Resources\\NonSpaceRaces.txt";
        StreamReader^ NonSpaceRacesReader = gcnew StreamReader(path, true);
        while(NonSpaceRacesReader->EndOfStream==false) {
            NonSpaceRaces[NonSpaceRacesCtr]=NonSpaceRacesReader->ReadLine();
            NonSpaceRacesCtr++;
        }
        NonSpaceRacesReader->Close();
        for(int i=0; i<StoriesCtr; i++) {
            StoryLength=Stories[i]->Length;
            GetVar(Stories[i]);
            this->StoryBox->Text+=Stories[i]+"\n";
        }
    }
    System::Void LifeBox_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        if(this->LifeBox->SelectedIndex!=0) {
            this->TerrestrialCheck->Enabled=true;
            this->MarineCheck->Enabled=true;
            this->SubglacialCheck->Enabled=true;
            this->FloatersCheck->Enabled=true;
            this->label16->Enabled=true;
        } else {
            this->TerrestrialCheck->Enabled=false;
            this->MarineCheck->Enabled=false;
            this->SubglacialCheck->Enabled=false;
            this->FloatersCheck->Enabled=false;
            this->label16->Enabled=false;
        }
    }
    void GetVar(String^ str) {//Finds variables in story, and replaces them with random information
        for(int a=0; a<str->Length; a++)
            subStory[a]=str->Substring(a, 1);
        for(int b=0; b<str->Length; b++) {
            if(subStory[b]=="%") {//Beginning of variable
                for(int c=(b+1); c<str->Length; c++) {
                    if(subStory[c]=="%") {//End of variable
                        for(int d=(b+1); d<c; d++)//Generates variable from substrings
                            var[varctr]+=subStory[d];
                        for(int e=0; e<=varctr; e++) {//Replaces instances of variables in story with randomly generated terms.
                            if(var[e]=="SpaceRace") {
                                this->StoryBox->Text+="SpaceRace: ";
                                RndHolder=Rnd->Next()%GetArrayLength(SpaceRaces);
                                this->StoryBox->Text+=RndHolder+"\n";
                                var[varctr]=SpaceRaces[RndHolder];
                                this->StoryBox->Text+=var[varctr]+"\n";
                                if(str->Contains("%SpaceRace%"))
                                    this->StoryBox->Text+="Contains SpaceRace"+"\n";
                                str->Replace("%SpaceRace%", var[varctr]);//Problem line
                            } else if(var[e]=="NonSpaceRace") {
                                this->StoryBox->Text+="NonSpaceRace: ";
                                RndHolder=Rnd->Next()%GetArrayLength(NonSpaceRaces);
                                this->StoryBox->Text+=RndHolder+"\n";
                                var[varctr]=NonSpaceRaces[RndHolder];
                                this->StoryBox->Text+=var[varctr]+"\n";
                                if(str->Contains("%SpaceRace%"))
                                    this->StoryBox->Text+="Contains NonSpaceRace"+"\n";
                                str->Replace("%NonSpaceRace%", var[varctr]);//Problem line
                            }
                        }
                        varctr++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int GetArrayLength(static array<String^>^ Array) {//Returns how many indexes of array are non-null
        for(int i=0; i<Array->Length; i++) {
            if(Array[i]==nullptr)
                return ArrayLength;
            ArrayLength++;
        }
        return ArrayLength;
    }
};
}
```

What output does look like:

```
SpaceRace: 9
Chevin
Contains SpaceRace
NonSpaceRace: 536
Vors‎
Contains NonSpaceRace
%SpaceRace% is a space-faring species in Star Wars, and %NonSpaceRace% is a non-space-fairing species in Star Wars.
```

What output should look like:

```
SpaceRace: 9
Chevin
Contains SpaceRace
NonSpaceRace: 536
Vors‎
Contains NonSpaceRace
Chevin is a space-faring species in Star Wars, and Vors is a non-space-fairing species in Star Wars.
```

Contents of Stories.txt (for reference):

```
%SpaceRace% is a space-faring species in Star Wars, and %NonSpaceRace% is a non-space-fairing species in Star Wars.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net c# replace string not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854465/asp-net-c-sharp-replace-string-not-working)

Comment: @DocMax
That's C#, this is C++.

Comment: It is, but both are .NET strings which is what matters in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.Replace` returns a new string with the replaced values and does not do an in-place replacement. Rather than:

```
str->Replace("%SpaceRace%", var[varctr]);
```

you need

```
str = str->Replace("%SpaceRace%", var[varctr]);
```

For more, see [the MSDN entry for String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

Comment: Well, that didn't solve the problem outright, but it does help. I'm making more progress now, thanks!